# How can I customize / edit shopify admin templates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

Please suggest a way to customize Shopify Admin Templates. Example - add a dropdown / anchor tag / some html code in all orders page / order details page.

I did research and could not find a way to implement the same. Any help shall be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.

The only option is to create a browser extension that will take action on .myshopify.com domains and will change the DOM on page load.